# Can I regenerate the the photo thumbnails that have turned black after restoring my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, photos.app

I had to restore my iOS 5.1 iPhone from iCloud after recieving a replacement. Many of the thumbnails for photographs are now black. Is there a way to regenerate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait and see. When I looked the following morning, the black thumbnails had all been regenerated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I may have experienced something similar the other day when my new iPad (3) arrived, and I restored to it from my original iPad (1) backup.  I happened to be in the Photos app (on the new iPad) when I initiated the syncing of my photos.  When it completed, I noticed that all my albums were now there in the Photos app—that none had thumbnails.

Solution (worked for me):
1. quit Photos (tap-and-hold on any icon, wait for the "jiggles" and then tap on the red "x" for the Photos app).
2. re-launch the Photos app.

Comment: My thumnails came back overnight. BTW I don't see the (x) on the Photos app at all when all apps are jiggling...